# PHPUnit: Find out where the headers has been sent

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a piece of code that I am testing with PHPUnit and I receive the following error:

```
session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent
```

I want to know the *location* where headers where sent; In general, when I test code in browser, I see a warning that mentions the location like this:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by 
(output started at /www/xxxx/x.php:52) in /www/xxxx/index.php on line 123
```

But in PHPUnit tests, there is no such info; PHPUnit only shows the error above and the backtrace:

```
/var/www/yii/framework/web/CHttpSession.php:166
/var/www/yii/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php:681
/var/www/yii/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php:214
...
```

which just points to where the error has happened.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

It tells you where the headers had been sent.
The solution will be to mock the session component in the test function.

```
$mockSession = $this->getMock('CHttpSession', array('regenerateID'));  
Yii::app()->setComponent('session', $mockSession);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but I do not use Yii. Here is how I solved it using `ob_*` functions:

I use a `phpunit.xml` config file which mentions a **bootstrap** file:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="phpunit_bootstrap.php">
    ...
</phpunit>
```

In `phpunit_bootstrap.php` I started by using [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

```
<?php
ob_start();
// some other configuration lines ...
```

Then I used 2 **PHPUnit** methods in the test class:

```
// Erase output buffer before starting the tests
public static function setUpBeforeClass(){
    ob_clean();
}

// Turn off output buffering after the tests
public static function tearDownAfterClass(){
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

---

- [`ob_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php)
- [`ob_end_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)
- [`setUpBeforeClass()` & `tearDownAfterClass()`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/fixtures.html#sharing-fixture)